# CSV table import: All rows from CSV file represented in one row in ArcMap attribute table

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, csv

When I import the following csv file, all rows only appear in one line in attribute table with the headings as "Field#".

I copied original excel export in new sheet where I pasted values only. I've never had this problem before with importing csv files in ArcMap. Any ideas?

[image: CSV file]

[image: attribute table]

Comment: It would help if you copied and pasted the first few lines of your CSV into the question.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work because while saving it defaulted to a CSV UTF-8 file type instead of a normal CSV file type. Once I changed to regular CSV file type, it worked just fine.  [image: csv utf-8]